# Can't select combobox entries after applying filter to column

Tags: ms-access

I have a column full of comboboxes. The comboboxes work fine on their own.

But if I right click on the column and apply a filter, e.g. sort alphabetically, the comboboxes still show with the correct entries, but I can no longer select another entry in the box. E.g. the box says "supplier", but I want to select "customer". Clicking on "customer" simply does nothing.

When I apply the filter, apparently the entire formula "refreshes" itself. Therefore I am currently trying to add some code to 
Private Sub Form_ApplyFilter(Cancel As Integer, ApplyType As Integer).

However, being rather new to MS Access, I have no idea whether this is a step in the right direction and if so, what code I should have in Form_ApplyFilter in order to make my comboboxes clickable/updateable again.

The properties of the comboboxes are:

```
Row source type = Table/Query
Row source = SELECT Tbl_Liability.ID,  Tbl_Liability.Liability FROM  Tbl_Liability; 
Bound column = 1 
Enabled = Yes
Locked = No
```

And the form the comboboxes are in has ALLOW FILTERS set to YES (but no code in Form_ApplyFilter).

Comment: Sorting is not filtering. I cannot replicate the issue. This is the first time I have even heard of ApplyFilter event. Need to provide the code.

Comment: @June7 Okay, say I am sorting and not filtering. Whatever it's called, Private Sub Form_ApplyFilter(Cancel As Integer, ApplyType As Integer) is called if I do this ( I have tested this with breakpoints). I currently have no code in this function, which might be part of the problem.
And I do not know what the Access code for rightclick -> sort by ... looks like. 
Which part of the code would you need?

Comment: Since I cannot replicate issue, cannot offer solution. I have no problem with right click sort or filter. I can still make selection in combobox regardless. However, I doubt code in OnApplyFilter event will resolve.